# Yii2 contact us page with Swiftmailer

Tags: php, yii2, swiftmailer

I used yii2 basic with swiftmailer that came together with Yii2.

I'm not using it to send out email, just to receive message via my `contact us` page. I got various message, while trying with my google email I got the security-related error where google view my apps could be malicious, even with my `allowed less secure apps accessing my account` turned to on.

I actually want to used my email provided with my `@domain.com`. My hosting provider is `hostgator`, so let's say I have made an `admin@domain.com` with my cpanel.

I have set my `adminEmail=>admin@domain.com` in my params, and configure the transport array in my web config

```
'mailer' => [
            'class' => 'yii\swiftmailer\Mailer',
            // send all mails to a file by default. You have to set
            // 'useFileTransport' to false and configure a transport
            // for the mailer to send real emails.
            'useFileTransport' => false,
            'transport' => [
                'class' => 'Swift_SmtpTransport',
            'host' => 'mail.domain.com',
            'username' => 'admin@domain.com',
            'password' => '*****',
            'port' => '993',
            'encryption' => 'ssl',
    ],
```

This is my email smtp setting from `hostgator`  (for privacy, I changed my actual domain name to `domain.com`

```
Username:   admin@domain.com
Password:   Use the email account’s password.
Incoming Server:    mail.domain.com
IMAP Port: 993 POP3 Port: 995
Outgoing Server:    mail.domain.com
SMTP Port: 465
IMAP, POP3, and SMTP require authentication.
```

As you can see, I need it just to receive email, not sending out, so I set the port to `993` , and later `995`. I also tried setting my class to `'class' => 'Swift_MailTransport'` as recommended by some in Stackoverflow, but still got an error message : `Connection to tcp://mail.domain.com:465 Timed Out`

Updated : Try with the outgoing port and `Swift_MailTransport` class combination but still got the same error.

What am I doing wrong here? I'm really stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**Updated : SOLVED. So I should have been using the outgoing port instead (in SO/google, few resources on people using swiftmailer just to receive email (majority use it to send out emails), so I wrongly assumed I should use incoming port. Along with that, I should configure correct configuration of my encryption to my respective available port. In my case, my hosting provider only provided me with port 465, thus the encyrption should match with `ssl`. Then it works! Thanks @tim for giving the hint**

Comment: you are sending, even to your self its still sending, so you want the SMTP port and server

Comment: @tim, I tried with the outgoing port (server is the same) but still the got same error. Any suggestion?

Comment: @tim Updated : solved! Looks like I should change the encryption type from `tsl` to `ssl` along with port `465`. Thanks!